# Convert escaped Unicode character back to actual character in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, unicode, encoding, postgresql-9.1

Is there a way how I can convert the following string back to the human-readable value? I have some external data where all non-ascii characters are escaped.

Example strings:

```
16 StringProvider_111=Telefon\u00ED kontakty
17 StringProvider_116=Odpov\u011Bdn\u00E1 osoba
```

Required Result:

```
16 StringProvider_111=Telefoní kontakty
17 StringProvider_116=Odpovědná osoba
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d7e61/1)

The database has UTF8 encoding and collation `cs_CZ.UTF-8`

Comment: Another useful answer is on this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10111654/398670 and there's more explanation on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23659685/398670

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One old trick is using parser for this purpose:

```
postgres=# select e'Telefon\u00ED kontakty';
     ?column?      
-------------------
 Telefoní kontakty
(1 row)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.unescape(text)
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE result text;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('SELECT e''%s''', $1) INTO result;
  RETURN result;
END;
$function$
```

It works, but it is SQL injection vulnerable - so you should to sanitize input text first!

Here is less readable, but safe version - but you have to manually specify one char as escape symbol:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.unescape(text, text) 
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 AS $function$
 DECLARE result text;
 BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT U&%s UESCAPE %s', 
                         quote_literal(replace($1, '\u','^')),
                         quote_literal($2)) INTO result;
   RETURN result;
 END;
 $function$
```

Result

```
postgres=# select unescape('Odpov\u011Bdn\u00E1 osoba','^');
    unescape     
-----------------
 Odpovědná osoba
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hi, how to solve non-canonic UTF8?  Seems de case of "Cecília" at `SELECT E'Ceci\u008Dlia';`, where instead í it use [diacrilic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks) "i+´"

Comment: @PeterKrauss - are you sure so \u008D is correct? I had to use `SELECT e'Ceci\u0301lia';`

Comment: Sorry (all readers) the comment before check UTF code points (I showed a case that **is not** diacrilic)... Thanks @PavelStehule, \u008D is not correct, not the expected result for Cecília. It is a bug encode on my input, seems aleatory code, only sometimes input result in correct diacrilic...I am [soving here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62416723/287948); and using a kind of spell corrector after clean the strange character.

Comment: Important about your 2013 parse-string  function `unescape()`  and **PostgreSQL project**: why in nowadays (2020) there is [no internal function for string unescape](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html)? The *5k pageviews  here + [3k pageviews here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10111654/287948)* shows that many programmers was looking for it (!)... Small continuous quality improvement needs small democracy, but there is no "user community demand" consensus mechanism to **vote on small optimizations** for pg library.  Perhaps we can use Stakoverflow as a first clue for it.

Comment: @PeterKrauss - PostgreSQL 14 will have an unistr function https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=f37fec837ce8bf7af408ba66d32099e5a0182402