# PostgreSQL : how to do UTF8 decode of this text 'gr\xc3\xa9gory'?

Tags: postgresql, encoding, utf-8, decode

In my PostgreSQL (9.3) database I have many field value like this  :

**'gr\xc3\xa9gory'**
And I need this : **Grégory**

Maybe it's some artifacts from an old UTF8 decode or base64...

Do you know how I can get **Grégory** result in my select ?

Thanks you for you experience

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert escaped Unicode character back to actual character in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124393/convert-escaped-unicode-character-back-to-actual-character-in-postgresql)

Comment: It can be but it's note the same pattern coding bug... Me its : '\xX1'. Here its : '\u00XX'

Comment: Yes, both are just literals. Give the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20125412/7925366) a try. E.g.: `SELECT E'gr\xc3\xa9gory';`

Comment: Cool ! Seems thats works !!
But I really need to make a function ? because value are in field ?

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't possible to use escape character `E` with identifiers, only with quoted strings, so you need the function to _grab_ the field value. More info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-BACKSLASH-TABLE).