# Can PostgreSQL convert entries to UTF-8 even though the input is Latin1?

Tags: postgresql, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have psql (PostgreSQL) 10.10 and client_encoding is UTF8. Now entries are made by an older Delphi version which cannot use UTF8 so the entries in the DB have the special signs not represented as UTF8. A ™ sign is represented by \u0099 for instance. Is it possible to force a conversion when the sign is entered into the data base? Switching Delphi is not an option right now. I am sorry if this is a basic question. My knowledge about data bases is limited.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124393/convert-escaped-unicode-character-back-to-actual-character-in-postgresql

Comment: How Latin1 is this Latin1? UTF8 and Latin1 use the *same* byte values for characters between 0-127. That covers all non-accented English letters

Comment: `which cannot use UTF8` it can and probably already does. Delphi supported Unicode in 2004 already (when I last used it). If the application uses characters in the US-ASCII range (0-127) it already works with "UTF8", as the actual bytes are identical.

Comment: This isn't a matter of switching Delphi. It's a buggy application that should never have used ASCII. Windows applications were expected to be Unicode by 2000. This application should have been rejected 20 years ago. The real fix is to switch all string types to Unicode types and recompile.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it is Delphi6 from 2000, so you are right.

Comment: @Namal I faced a similar case back in 2004. It was already preposterous to produce an ASCII version back then.  Someone created an ASCII Delphi app for a factory's salespeople cheaply then charged for "localized" versions where all they did was create a new binary with different resource strings. The client didn't want to pay for a fix or a different app though, because individual "localized" versions were always cheaper than a (cheap) rewrite. Not even if the rewrite cost just 2x the "localized" version. They paid quite a bit more this way, little by little.

Comment: @S-Man, unfortunatelly it does not. I tried out the unescape function, it works for the represented example. But ™ = \u0099 does not work, it simply does not change

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your Delphi client is *not* using LATIN1, but WINDOWS-1252, because ™ is code point 99 in that encoding.

You can change `client_encoding` per session, and that is what you should do.

Either let your application execute

```
SET client_encoding = WIN1252;
```

or set the `PGCLIENTENCODING` environment variable or specify `client_encoding` as part of the connect string.

Comment: Do I understand it right? So it is wrong to set the database to UTF8 when created? And if I push LATIN1 data sets to it and it is set to latin1 it will be UTF8 when I extract the data?

Comment: @Namal: it's perfectly OK to set the database to UTF-8. You just need to make sure your _client_ uses the correct encoding when it sends and receives the data to/from the server

Comment: In Delphi I have 'codepage=latin1' propery setting for my connection, shouldn't it do the trick?

Comment: @Namal No, you have to tell PostgreSQL too, so that it knows that the application will feed it LATIN1 characters and can convert them to UTF-8 correctly.

Comment: Hello Laurence, so I am executing an SQL 'SET client_encoding = LATIN1;' statement in Delphi, I ask delphi show client_encoding which is Latin1. But when I update a field with special sign (by the delphi program) it is still represented as \u0099 etc. If I ask  client_encoding directly in the console it returns SQL_ASCII. So unfortunatelly this doesn't help.

Comment: Looking again, I see that your Delphi does not use LATIN1 of course, because ™ cannot be represented in LATIN1. So try with `WIN1252`, like my updated answer recommends.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres SQL use this command to update to UTF-8

**also replace database_name with your database name**

```
update pg_database set encoding = pg_char_to_encoding('UTF8') where datname='database_name';
```