# function convert_from(character varying, unknown) does not exist in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

When i'm trying to convert from unicode to utf8 in the code below
**"function convert_from(character varying, unknown) does not exist"** error occurs.

```
select convert_from(artists, 'UTF8') from songs where     
to_tsvector('simple',convert_from(artists, 'UTF8')) 
  @@ plainto_tsquery('simple','alizee') 
limit 100
```

Column "**artists**" has "TEXT" type.

But when I'm running

```
select convert_from(E'\u0422\u0438\u043c\u0430\u0442\u0438', 'UTF8');
```

it works well.

How can I resolve this problem?
I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Please show a sample of a value in the `artists` column. You can't store "unicode" (assuming you mean utf-16/utf-32/ucs-2/ucs-4) in a PostgreSQL `text` field, because it contains null bytes, which in a `text` field terminate the string. So whatever's going on, there isn't enough information here to guess. **Show the data** by editing the question, then comment here when you are done.

Comment: sample value of artists column: "brig\u0442\u0438ada"

Comment: aah, so it's actually *text* with unicode character escapes. That's very different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20124393/398670, http://stackoverflow.com/q/10111654/398670

Answer (score 5):

From [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html): `convert_from(string bytea, src_encoding name)`.
So cast artists to bytea:

```
select convert_from(artists::bytea, 'UTF8') from songs where     
to_tsvector('simple',convert_from(artists, 'UTF8')) 
  @@ plainto_tsquery('simple','alizee') 
limit 100
```

Comment: select convert_from(artists::bytea, 'UTF8') from songs where     
to_tsvector('simple',convert_from(artists::bytea, 'UTF8')) 
  @@ plainto_tsquery('simple','alizee') 
limit 100. Another error occured: "ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bytea"

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like you've taken data in the form of 7-bit ascii with 2-byte unicode hex escapes (`\uxxxx`) and stored it in a `varchar` typed field.

`convert_from` is entirely the wrong way to handle that data. It isn't utf-8 except in that 7-bit ASCII is a subset of utf-8. If you forced it through `convert_from(..., 'utf-8')` you'd get exactly what you started with, `blah\u0123` etc.

The reason that `select convert_from(E'\u0422\u0438\u043c\u0430\u0442\u0438', 'UTF8');` *appears* to work is that the `convert_from` does nothing. Here's what happens:

- PostgreSQL sees the literal value `E'\u0422\u0438\u043c\u0430\u0442\u0438'` and sees that `convert_from` wants `bytea` input.
- PostgreSQL parses the escape-string format of the string literal, decoding the unicode escapes to produce the utf-8 string `Тимати`. At this point it's as if you wrote:

  ```
  SELECT convert_from('Тимати', 'utf-8')
  ```
- Because `convert_from` wants `bytea` input, PostgreSQL implicitly casts the data to `bytea`, converting the text string to utf-8 encodied binary because that's your database server's text encoding. Now it's as if you wrote:

  ```
  SELECT convert_from( convert_to('Тимати','utf-8'), 'utf-8')
  ```

  which when the first conversion is done gets turned into:

  ```
  SELECT convert_from(BYTEA '\xd0a2d0b8d0bcd0b0d182d0b8', 'utf-8');
  ```

So effectively your `convert_from` is a very slow and inefficient way to do nothing at all.

It doesn't work that way for a column value instead of a literal, because PostgreSQL will implicitly cast unknown-typed literals in ways it won't implicitly cast known-type column values like `varchar` column. That's a type-safety thing.

So, to *correctly* convert your data, you need to decode those `\u` escapes. `convert_from` is *not* what you want for that, because it's designed for *converting binary representations of encoded text into the local database text encoding*.

PostgreSQL supports that for string literals, as we've determined by seeing what it's doing for `E''` literals. I'm currently looking for a function that exposes that decoding to the user, though. `decode(...)` doesn't support `\u` escapes, only octal escapes...