# PostgreSQL: select URI escaped value of a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, escaping

I have a column with some text, e.g.:

```
fURM0z0xYdBVojkfDDu4/WM9MHCRgN2ddmzAhnA6/zDORXfqgtfM+PGKFjirO/JY
```

I need to write a select query so that I get the URI escaped value of this text as

```
fURM0z0xYdBVojkfDDu4%2FWM9MHCRgN2ddmzAhnA6%2FzDORXfqgtfM%2BPGKFjirO%2FJY
```

How to do this? If it is possible.

Comment: Have you tried using convert_to?  Maybe this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659685/function-convert-fromcharacter-varying-unknown-does-not-exist-in-postgres

Comment: @RăzvanGabrielRujoiu does not seem to work

Comment: You are talking about URL escaping, not UTF-8 encoding.