# Select strange characters on text, not working with LIKE operator

Tags: postgresql, encode, detection

I try to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20125412/287948) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10116805/287948) (for `str_eval()`) but seems other encode or other UTF8's *Normalization Form*, perhaps [combining diacritical marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks)...

```sql
select distinct  logradouro, str_eval(logradouro)  
from logradouro where logradouro like '%CECi%';
--         logradouro         |          str_eval
------------------------------+----------------------------
-- AV CECi\u008DLIA MEIRELLES | AV CECi\u008DLIA MEIRELLES
```

**PROBLEM**: how to select all rows of the table where the problem exists?
That is, where `\u` occurs?

- not works with `like '%CECi\u%'` neither `like '%CECi\\u%'`
- works with `like E'%CECi\u008D%'` but **is not generic**

---

For Google, edited after solved question: this is a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250659/205446). In the original question (above) I used **~wrong hypothesis**.  All the solutions bellow are answers to the following (objective) question:

### How to select only printable ASCII text?

"[Printable ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters)" is a subset of UTF8, it is *"all ASCII that is not a 'control character'"*.

The "non-printable" control characters are UNICODE hexadecimal 00 to 1F and 7F
(HTML entity `&#x00;` to `&#x1F;` + `&#x7F;` or decimal 0 to 31 + 127).

PS1: the zero (`&#x00;`) is the "end of text" mark of PostgreSQL *text* datatype internal representation, so not need to be checked, but no problems to include it in the range.

PS2: about the secondary question *"how to convert a word with encode bug to a valid word?"*,
 see an [heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_(computer_science)) at  [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62416723/287948).

Comment: Exactly which code points do you want to exclude? Only 1 to 31?

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe, was an ugly input with an encode bug, but 90% of strings are ASCII, so to detect the rows with bug I need only to check non-ASCII, them add some simple filter. The encode problem is that it prints as strange text on Postgresql but when export with COPY it is not visible, and when check by LIKE not selectable... It  prints with `\u....` but no regular or previsible code point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition will exclude any strings that do not entirely consist of printable ASCII characters:

```
logradouro ~ '[^\u0020-\u007E]'
```

Comment: Thanks, same count(), so confirmed solution! A secondary question: why psql prints some words as `ITA\u0081LIA` with `\u`  and others, like `DIONÍZIO` and `3º`, with good visual representation? It is only for "control characters" of a specific range?

Comment: Right. It's the "non-printable"  control characters UNICODE 01 - 1F.

Comment: oops, 7F is  DEL, see HTML `&#x7F;` must be excluded.

Comment: There are more characters, changed the answer.

Comment: Oops, was near perfect, the edit introduced "invalid character range" error.  You can use `\u0000-\u001F` instead of `\u0020-\u001F`... But the list of strings *using not-printable characters* is in the condiction `logradouro ~ '[\u0000-\u001F\u007F-\u00A0]'`, and negation to *excludes* is `!~`

Comment: Brain fart, sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Solving with workaround

```sql
select distinct  logradouro, str_eval(logradouro)
from logradouro where not(logradouro ~ E'^[a-zA-Z0-9_,;\\- \\.\\(\\)\\/"\'\\*]+$');
```

There is a systematic bug on encode, no way to convert to correct UTF8... Even converting, the problem is that "CECi\u008DLIA" is not "CECíLIA".

The solution is to use  a kind of "heuristic spell corrector" on

```sql
regexp_replace(logradouro, E'[^a-zA-Z0-9_,;\\- \\.\\(\\)\\/"\'\\*]+', '!')
```

Example: the `i!` of "Ceci!lia" is corrected to `í`.

---

NOTICE. Any heuristic solution (or neural network) trained with a specific dataset (specific [systematic error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observational_error#Random_errors_versus_systematic_errors) source) is a [black box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box) solution, **valid only for that type of systematic  error**. There is no generalization for this type of problem.